# How to cut off symbols that travel off-screen?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a sidescroller game with a rather large level (about 16000 pixels wide). The document resolution is 1152x768. A problem that occurs is that when maximizing the Flash Player window you are able to see the symbol that travel outside of the stage before being destroyed.

A picture would make this far more clear:
!(http://oi44.tinypic.com/2mhdapl.jpg)

I was told that you could crop the stage with a simple command. But I can't seem to find any info in it. Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 1):

- create a mask rectangle on the root thats the same size as your stage, only whats under the mask will be visible:
  http://coursesweb.net/flash/creating-mask-layers-flash

OR

- change the embed properties of the swf so nothing bleeds off the stage